# Laravel 8: How to insert data into One To One relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a project in Laravel 8 and in this project, I have **One To One** relationship between `movies` and `imdbs` tables.

So I have added these to Models:

`Movie.php`:

```
public function imdb()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Imdb::class);
    }
```

`Imdb.php`:

```
public function movie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Movie::class);
    }
```

Then I created a form for adding movies. Here is the `store` method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new = new Movie();
        $new->name = $request->name;
        $new->link = $request->link;
        $new->year = $request->year;
        $new->actor = $request->actor;
        $new->director = $request->director;
        $new->imdb = $request->imdb;
        $new->starred = $request->starred;
        $new->watched = $request->watched;
        $new->save();
    }
```

As you can see `$new->imdb = $request->imdb;` is for inserting imdb rate but this data should be added to `imdbs` table and not `movies` table!

So, how can I do that?

Here is also `imdbs` table migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('imdbs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('rate');
            $table->integer('movie_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

### Update 1

```
         @foreach($movies  as $movie)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $movie->id }}</th>
                <td>{{ $movie->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movie->year }}</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>{{ $movie->imdb->rate }}</td>
                <td>@mdo</td
                <td><a href="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

And then this gives me:

> **ErrorException** Trying to get property 'rate' of non-object

And `$movies` is coming from this method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $movies = Movie::all();
        return view('admin.movies.index', compact(['movies']));
    }
```

Comment: You should add a new row to the imdbs table then ```$new->imdb``` should be ```$new->imdb_id``` surely? with a column rename on movies

Comment: @Ballard Can you explain more as an Answer please

Comment: my mistake I didn't see your movie_id on the imdb table

Comment: yOu can reduce your codes by trying my answer @KKKKKK

Comment: Thank u for the answers, but when I want to get the rate of movie like this: `{{ $movie->imdb->rate }}`, I get `Trying to get property 'rate' of non-object` error!

Comment: @KKKKKK can u share Your response?

Comment: @JEJ I just added **UPDATE** ,

Comment: @KKKKKK use another foreach($movie->imdb as $imdb) then use $imdb->rate

Comment: @JEJ `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: @KKKKKK can you dd($movie)?.. if  $movie->imdb is an array then u have to use foreach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231794/discussion-between-kkk-kkk-and-jej).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On store of your `Movie` model, just make an `IMDB` model with the `movie_id` from the model you've just created.

I would suggest doing some validation of your request data too, which would look something like:

```
$data = $request->validate([
    //validation fields
]);

$movie = Movie::create($data);
```

Otherwise, the solution to your issue is:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $movie = new Movie();
        $movie->name = $request->name;
        $movie->link = $request->link;
        $movie->year = $request->year;
        $movie->actor = $request->actor;
        $movie->director = $request->director;
        $movie->starred = $request->starred;
        $movie->watched = $request->watched;
        $movie->save();

        if(!is_null($movie)) {
            $imdb = new Imdb();
            $imdb->rate = $request->imdb;
            $imdb->movie_id = $movie->id;
            $imdb->save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get `General error: 1364 Field 'imdb' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: because you need to drop that column from the table @KKKKKK - see the fields I've added in the creation of the movie model.

Comment: After you get this working, you should switch to @JEJ's answer

Answer (score 2):

delete column imbd from movies table then

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    { 
    $data = $request->only([
            'name','link','year','actor','director','starred','watched'
        ]);
     $movie=Movie::create($data);
     $imdb=$request->only(['imbd']);
     $imbd=$movie->imdb()->create($imbd);
}
```

Comment: This is a far more elegant solution than mine, see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-a-portion-of-the-input-data for info on how it works